# How can I modify this code to count the same object in a normal Microsoft word table

Tags: vba, checkbox, count, ms-word

Following code is for counting the number of checked checkboxes in a formfield. How can I modify it to count the same object in a normal table, and not a form field?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
k = 0
With ActiveDocument
    With .Tables(1)
        j = 3
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If .Cell(i, j).Range.FormFields(1).CheckBox.Value = True Then
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next i
        i = .Rows.Count
    End With
End With
    MsgBox k & " instances were found"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `ContentControls` property of the `Range` object to return a [`ContentControls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192425.aspx) object and exploit it

here's some examples of how to count checkboxes or checked checkboxes in a table or a in a single column of it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    With ActiveDocument
        MsgBox CountCheckBoxes(.Tables(1)) & " CheckBox instances were found"
        MsgBox CountCheckedCheckBoxes(.Tables(1)) & " checked CheckBox instances were found"
        MsgBox CountCheckBoxesInColumn(.Tables(1), 1) & " CheckBox instances were found in column 1"
        MsgBox CountCheckedCheckBoxesInColumn(.Tables(1), 1) & " checked CheckBox instances were found in column 1"
    End With
End Sub

Private Function CountCheckBoxes(table As table, Optional col As Variant) As Long
    Dim cc As ContentControl

    With table
        For Each cc In .Range.ContentControls
            If cc.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then CountCheckBoxes = CountCheckBoxes + 1
        Next cc
    End With
End Function

Private Function CountCheckedCheckBoxes(table As table) As Long
    Dim cc As ContentControl

    With table
        For Each cc In .Range.ContentControls
            If cc.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then If cc.Checked Then CountCheckedCheckBoxes = CountCheckedCheckBoxes + 1
        Next cc
    End With
End Function

Private Function CountCheckBoxesInColumn(table As table, col As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With table
        For i = 1 To .Rows.count
            CountCheckBoxesInColumn = CountCheckBoxesInColumn + .Cell(i, col).Range.ContentControls.count
        Next i
    End With
End Function

Private Function CountCheckedCheckBoxesInColumn(table As table, col As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With table
        For i = 1 To .Rows.count
            CountCheckedCheckBoxesInColumn = CountCheckedCheckBoxesInColumn + CountCheckBoxesCheked(.Cell(i, col).Range)
        Next i
    End With
End Function

Function CountCheckBoxesCheked(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim cc As ContentControl

    With rng
        For Each cc In .ContentControls
            If cc.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then If cc.Checked Then CountCheckBoxesCheked = CountCheckBoxesCheked + 1
        Next cc
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: That's really great! Thanks a lot!